# NodeJS: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning during changing password

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling, change-password

I'm working on password changing in NodeJS and I get following error during my request processing:

```
(node:16220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/pbaj/Documents/Projects/syberiaquotes-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/pbaj/Documents/Projects/syberiaquotes-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/pbaj/Documents/Projects/syberiaquotes-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at user.(anonymous function).updateOne.then.catch.err (/home/pbaj/Documents/Projects/syberiaquotes-backend/api/controllers/user.js:284:52)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:16220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

In my `changePassword` route I take `email,password,newPassword` values and:

1. checking if email exist, if yes...
2. comparing given password and user password, if they are the same...
3. `bcrypt.hash` function take newPassword, making hash from it, and save to mongoDB

If I give correct email and password, all points above are done but I get that `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

I see that the reason of this issue is inside `user[0].updateOne(user[0])` function, exactly in `catch()` but I don't know what's going on.

```js
// CHANGE USER PASSWORD
exports.changePassword = (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed'
            })
        }

        const { password, newPassword } = req.body
        console.log(password, newPassword)
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
            console.log(result)
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Error! Something goes wrong'
                })
            }
            if (result) {
                bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    console.log(hash)
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            error: err
                        })
                    } else {
                        user[0].password = hash
                        user[0]
                        .updateOne(user[0])
                        .then(result => {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                message: 'Password changed!',
                                result: result,
                            })
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed'
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err })
    })
}
```

I need to get `[200]'Password changed!'` answer from my request, but I'm getting `[401]'Auth failed'` becouse of `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Comment: Do you have any middelware that'll respond with a 401?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send response 2 times. Try this code

```
 if (result) {
            bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10, (err, hash) => {
                console.log(hash)
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    })
                } else {
                    user[0].password = hash
                    user[0]
                    .updateOne(user[0])
                    .then(result => {
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            message: 'Password changed!',
                            result: result,
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
                    })
                }
            })
} else {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
          })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Mongoose (because of `User.find(...)`).

If that's the case, you can't do `user[0].updateOne(...)`, because `user[0]` is already an object of type `User`.

You either do [`User.findOneAndUpdate(...)`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate), or you do `user[0].save(...)` after you set the new password (which seems more straightforward to me).

Comment: `updateOne()` is actually defined on the document: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-updateOne

Comment: @c1moore, thanks for pointing that. I wasn't aware of that and IMO it doesn't make too much sense to have that method.